# Counting (arrangement in a line)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I'm having a tough time figuring this problem out :

*How many ways may 10 students be arranged in a line so that student 6 always comes before student 2*

I've tried to do it by cases:
case 1: Student 6,2 adjacent 
case 2: student 2 last
case 3: student 6 first

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math Stack Exchange! To get the best answers at your level, to learn most of it and to prevent people form giving hints you already know, you need to include some information about what you have tried. You can edit your post to include this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the number of all outcomes:
$10!$.

Second notice that the arrangement of student 6 and student 2 has $2!$ ways, but only the case "student 6 before student 2" is needed, so there is $1$ way out of the $2$ ways.

Thus the number of the case is $10!/2=1814400.$

Answer (score 0):

Use a symmetric argument and then divide all cases by two...

Comment: are my cases correct?

Comment: Better two take two cases according to who comes first and then use symmetry.